# How to add/include altered package into final image? [Yocto Project]

Tags: build, yocto, bitbake

I have recently started using Yocto. I 'm looking for option to include/add altered package into final build image. Below I have described the scenario.

I'm working on [RDK](https://rdkcentral.com/), which is yocto based system for STB(Set-top Box) Emulator. I have already build complete system once. Now I'm making some changes in some particular module, to see final effect of that in build/image, I rebuilt that particular module(at this point I came to know bitbake doesn't work like makefile utility, that you make changes and it will take care of rest and your package will be compiled as well as included into final image/binary), I used `bitbake -c cleansstate <module_name>`, then `bitbake <module_name>` to rebuild the package.
Next thing was to get it inside the final image, but the same thing I had to go through the pain again, `bitbake -c cleansstate <image_name>`, then `bitbake <image_name>` to rebuild the image.

Basically, only once package is changed and to include that into final image I have create complete image again.
Which is very time-consuming process!!!
I'm wondering **is there any way that I can reduce this build time and include altered package into final image?**

**NOTE**: Not looking for optimization option, I know about local.conf `BB_NUMBER_THREADS` and `PARALLEL_MAKE` options. It is just about, can we add package into final image without generating all dependency for final image as described in scenario.

Comment: Bitbake generates hash to check whether it has to rebuild the package (in case you've made any changes to it's recipe) or not. If you are changing some package (or running cleansstate), bitbake will rebuild it and rebuild all the packages that depends on it. For example if you will rebuild glibc, at least half of the packages will be rebuild as a result. If this is the case, it's normal bitbake behavior. Or you want to say that all of your packages are rebuilding each time you run cleansstate?

Comment: No, I guess you get the question wrong somewhat. I have one servicemanager, I'm updating source code to that by adding another service. I get it, cleansstate servicemanager will remove object of it only and I can rebuild it with new/updated source code. Now the question is, How to add this package into final image, as final image will have older package, and I want newly built package to use newly added service. To do that I have cleansstate my image and rebuild it, that takes 1 hr approx time, I would like to reduce that if we can include package some other way!!

Comment: Building of your image itself takes an hour, or a lot of packages are rebuilding after cleansstate? If your image recipe is a set of packages and doesn't contain any code to be built (which is normally the case), cleansstate and rebuild shouldn't take much time (about 5 mins on my computer for my project), it essentially only builds rootfs from already built packages and pack it to archive. Saying module, you mean kernel module? I can suppose that kernel module rebuild triggers rebuild of the kernel, which takes a lot of time. What CPU r u using and what number of threads have you specified?

Comment: No kernel module, it's one of the system services that I'm altering/updateing. And while I'm doing cleansstate and build again only one task executes and that is image building, but in my case, it generates different rootfs (~3 gigs) and hdddirect(~3 gigs) files for final VMDK(~1.7 gigs) creation/genration. I guess writing these file onto HDD takes this much time. But If there is way that can reduce overhead on HDD and also save some time too. Look into RDK-V development, you might get more idea.

Comment: As a workaround you can try to mount your image (e.g. `archivemount`, but I'm not sure it will work with .vmdk), change files you want to change and save the changes to the image. It is a pretty bad architecture decision though, and also it is out of scope of yocto capabilities. Generally speaking there is nothing wrong with your situation, as bitbake needs to create a big rootfs, compress it and compress it once again. This is a time consuming operation.

Comment: Actually yea...I figured while working, and it's the origin of this question. I will try with `archivemount` to give it a try, though being an non-standard (odd) way! :p Have you tried with below suggestion ever, suggestion please. After our discussion I highly doubt that it will help me in reducing time!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "making changes" you mean modifying the underlying code, I would suggest using `devtool modify` - this will set up a local source tree for the recipe where you can make your changes, and each time you make a change and then run bitbake on the recipe or something that depends upon it (such as your image) it will rebuild it including your changes. Basic steps:

1. `devtool modify <recipe>`
2. Make your changes within the source tree that is set up
3. `bitbake <recipe>` or `bitbake <image>`
4. Test the result; loop back to step 2 if you need to make further changes
5. `devtool finish <recipe>` to write your changes back as patches against the recipe

Comment: can you please guide me as I'm unable to get along with `devtool` itself, I tried to install it using help of online forums that suggests to install it using `R`, but `R` itself giving me trouble. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS, the reason behind this release is RDK on which I'm working is supported on this release only.

Comment: Is it python script form `<yocto>/poky/scripts/devtool`? Just want to confirm, am I looking into right direction or not?!

Answer (score 0):

I happened to me that after adding a recipe on `meta/recipes-extended/myrecipe_0.0.1.bb`
I was able to build my new recipe with the command

```
bitbake myrecipe
```

but the binaries never got included on the rootfs image when running

```
bitbake core-image-minimal
```

To add the output of my recipe to the output images, I've added the following to my ${BUILDDIR}/conf/local.conf file:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " myrecipe"
```

in my local.conf file.